# How to get results count in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
TB_Departament  
(  
id_dep, nome  
1 , RRHH  
2 , Security  
3 , logistics  
)  

TB_Incident  
(  
id_tipo, id_dep  
1 , 1  
2 , 3  
1 , 3  
2 , 1  
1 , 3  
2 , 1  
2 , 1  
)
```

If I count the *records department* get this:

```
select d.nome, count(i.id_tipo) as Num from TB_Departament d, TB_Incident i 
where i.id_dep = d.id_dep
group by d.nome
```

resp:

```
RRHH 4  
logistics 3
```

but I need this:

```
RRHH 4   
Security 0  
logistics 3
```

How can i modify the query to get the right answer?

Comment: You need to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than the `INNER JOIN`. Please look up the syntax for your chosen platform; I would also consider using the more modern ANSI syntax, but that isn't necessary to make this function.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT d.nome, count(i.id_tipo)
FROM TB_Departament d LEFT JOIN
     TB_Incident i 
     ON d.id_dep = i.id_dep
GROUP BY d.nome
```

Answer (score 0):

ON MSSQL, this would be as follow, including an order by clause in case you want the results to come out by id_dep #

```
SELECT x.name,x.Num FROM (      
select d.id_dep, d.name AS name, count(i.id_tipo) AS Num from TB_Department d
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB_Incident i 
ON i.id_dep= d.id_dep
group by d.name, d.id_dep) AS x
ORDER BY x.id_dep
```